# How to stop es6 promise flow execution?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

How to stop Promise.then execution without .catch function execution?

```
Promise
.resolve("a")
.then(function(a){
    console.log("step1 = " + a);
    return a;
})
.then(function(a){
    console.log("step2 = " + a);
    if (!someReason) {                
        return Promise.reject(); // I whant to stop flow execution here
    }        
})
.then(function(a){
    console.log("step3 = " + a);
    return a;
})
.catch(function(err){
// I don't whant to have .catch() executed in case of planned stop
   console.log("Flow failed");
});
```

Comment: Your code works fines, I never see console.log("step3 = " + a) output, but promise is left pending.

Comment: Silly question but you never know who knows what sooo... what do you mean by "want to stop flow execution here".... specifically.

Comment: My sample executes function in .catch(), I want to avoid it. So question is more about symantic. For example, I don't whant to call catch() for case if I got data from cache and I don't want to call next .thens to get data from database.

Comment: You need to refactor your code with a different logic flow, do you know how?

Comment: I'm just looking something like 
Promise.rejectWithoutCatchCall() or another way to make code readable and consistent. As I understand, I can return step3 promise in step2, but in will be nested. Currently I'm trying to avoid nesting by promises.

Comment: @musuk: Branching (which is what you want here) always comes with nesting (if you don't resort to `goto`). Just do it.